# Changes the voice from woman to man in Google Translate

Tags: google-translate

In Google Translate, how do you change the English voice from female to male?

Comment: What languages are you using? AFAIK, the speaker/voice is based on the language you're translating to.

Comment: When I change the English Dialects to UK Australia or Us it's the same woman speaking.

Comment: It's 2021 and this does not yet seem possible (android 11, pixel 4), (existing answer option exists, but didn't make a difference)

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings > Language & input > Text-to-speech output.
Hit the Settings icon next to "Google text-to-speech engine". Under installing voice data you can select if you want male or female.

[Link to related answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/MotoX/comments/26zsw1/change_the_spoken_voice_output_from_google_now/)

Comment: This answer does not seem to apply to google translate (the option exists, but has no affect on the translate app) (Android 11, pixel 4)