# TTS voice not applied in Google Translate

Tags: android-12, google-translate

The voice in Google Translate was configurable before Android 12. Any one knows how to do it on Android 12?

App: Google Translate and Google TTS
OS: Android 12
Phone: Pixel 5

Comment: Related: [Changes the voice from woman to man in Google Translate](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/104521/44325).

Comment: I asked because that doesn't work.